# Regex word boundary issue when angle brackets are adjacent to the boundary

Tags: regex, word-boundary

Regex:

```
\b< low="" number="" low="">\b
```

Example string:

```
 <b22>Aquí se muestran algunos síntomas < low="" number="" low=""> tienen el siguiente aspecto.</b22>
```

I'm not sure why the word boundary between **síntomas** and **<** is not being found.  Same problem exists on the other side between **>** and **tienen**

Suggestions on how I might more properly match this boundary?

When I give it the following input, the Regex matches as expected:

```
Aquí se muestran algunos síntomas< low="" number="" low="">tienen el siguiente aspecto.
```

removing the edge conditions \b `\bPHRASE\b` are not an option because it cannot match parts of words

**Update**

This did the trick: (Thanks to *Igor*, *Mosty*, *DK* and *NickC*)

```
Regex(String.Format(@"(?<=[\s\.\?\!]){0}(?=[\s\.\?\!])", innerStringToMatch);
```

I needed to improve my boundary matching to `[\s\.\?\!]` and make these edge matches positive lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: I believe that `\b` would only work for alphanumeric "words". You can use a manual character class like `[^A-Za-z0-9<>_]`.

Comment: It looks like < is being counted as a word-breaker, not a word-continuer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` is a zero-length match which can occur between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character. Word character is defined as [A-Za-z0-9_]<sup>*</sup>. `<` is not a word character, that's why `\b` doesn't match.

You can try the following regex instead (`(?: )` is a [non-capturing parentheses group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)):

```
(?:\b|\s+)< low="" number="" low="">(?:\b|\s+)
```

---

*) Actually, this is not correct for all regex engines. To be precise, \b matches between `\w` and `\W`, where `\w` matches any *word character*. As Tim Pietzcker pointed out in the comment to this answer, the meaning of "word character" differs between implementations, but I don't know any where `\w` matches `<` or `>`.

Comment: The definition of `\w` varies wildly between regex implementations. In Python, it respects the current locale if you ask it to, in .NET it is completely Unicode-aware, in JavaScript it really only matches ASCII alnums etc...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: you're absolutely right, but what's important in this particular scenario is that `\w` doesn't match `<` or `>` in any implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to do the following:

```
\s< low="" number="" low="">\s
```