# php preg_replace using arrays - first or last letter having an accented character does not work

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, diacritics

In this example I have the word así which ends in the the accented i character.

```
 $str = "A string containing the word así which should be changed to color purple";

  $prac[] = "/\basí\b/i";
  $prac2[] = "<span class='readword'  style='color:purple'>\$0 </span>";

 $str= preg_replace($prac,$prac2,$str);

 echo $str;
```

It does not change. But if I have a word that does not end or begin with an accented character it DOES change. For example:

```
 $str = "A string containing another word which should be changed to color 
  purple";
  $prac[] = "/\banother word\b/i";
  $prac2[] = "<span class='readword'  style='color:purple'>\$0 </span>";

 $str= preg_replace($prac,$prac2,$str);

 echo $str;
 ?>
```

If the accent is in the middle of the word it always works also. Also I tested the array itself and preg_replace itself with the word. There does not appear to be a problem with the word with either the array or preg_replace. It is only when I am using an array as a parameter in preg_replace.

Please help, can't find any information on this anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, see Toto's answer, should definitely be put as the correct answer in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the unicode flag:

```
$str = "A string containing the word así which should be changed to color purple";
$prac[] = "/\basí\b/iu";
#             here __^
$prac2[] = "<span class='readword'  style='color:purple'>\$0 </span>";
$str= preg_replace($prac,$prac2,$str);
echo $str;
```

**Result for given example:**

```
A string containing the word <span class='readword'  style='color:purple'>así </span> which should be changed to color purple
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently an accented character is considered itself as a word boundary by PHP, and the 3 conditions to match a word boundary `\b` are:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a    word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last    character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,    where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Source: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

So when you use `/\basí\b/i` to match `así` inside the string it wouldn't cause no one of the 3 cited conditions is met, the first and second are obvious because `así` is in the middle of the string, and the third says that to match `\b` in the string we need two characters where one is a word character and the other is not, here we have `í` and space  which are both not word characters.

After all not sure if my understanding is correct too.

For a solution you may replace your reg exp by `/\basí(\b|\s+)/i`

Check also [Regex word boundary issue when angle brackets are adjacent to the boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087521/regex-word-boundary-issue-when-angle-brackets-are-adjacent-to-the-boundary)

And http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89471

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. It worked initially but I was still having problems with this. Another answer here worked.

Comment: @JonathanKortes No problem, the subject was informative for me too, good question.